Passing colors as a list to matplotlib
I have a plot with x of shape 180 and y of shape 36, 180. So I have 36 lines when I call plot. How do I set the first 30 to blue and the last six to red without calling a loop?
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = np.linspace(0, 10, 180) 
y = np.random.rand(36, 180) 


colors = ['blue'] * 30 + ['red'] * 6 

plt.plot(x, y.T, color=colors)  

plt.show()

However this returns the following error:
ValueError: ['blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red'] is not a valid value for color


Plot the blue lines and then plot the red lines.

If you really want to use a list of colors, you can create a LineCollection https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/shapes_and_collections/line_collection.html

@RuthC each one of the 36 lines is the same color either blue or red, I think there is no need for LineCollection
